# Material doesn't have a texture property '_RendererColor'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to scroll ball texture to show its moving so I have written this kind of code:

```
// ball texture rolling
textureOffset.x -= myRigidBody.velocity.normalized.z * (speed / 500f);
textureOffset.y = myRigidBody.velocity.normalized.x * (speed / 40);
myMaterial.mainTextureOffset = Vector2.Lerp (myMaterial.GetTextureOffset (1), textureOffset, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

I was getting this kind of error during game play in Unity Editor.
[image]

This kind of material assigned to ball object:

[image]

I have just upgraded Unity version 2017.3.1p4 and error started coming, I don't know what to do now. Give me suggestions to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of reasons for this bug, so here is a few suggestions :

1-make sure the shader you are using has the texture "_RendererColor", look for something like this

```
Properties {
_RendererColor ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
```

maybe they might have changed it's name in the update

2-make sure your shader has the appropriate include file like for example

```
include "UnityCG.cginc"
```

maybe some functionality requires certain includes after the update

3-this could just be a random bug after unity crashes or after a update, I have had some friends have their unity crash for them then they get bugs like this, maybe updating unity might do something similar, maybe try to remake the shader/create a new one and replace this one.

This is all I can think of